# Clean way to make an object of many selector values

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there a simple or shorter way to do the following code?

```
const name = document.querySelector('#name').value
const city = document.querySelector('#city').value
const duration = document.querySelector('#duration').value
const employerName = document.querySelector('#employerName').value
const phoneNumber = document.querySelector('#phoneNumber').value
const summary = document.querySelector('#summary').value

const values = {
  name: name,
  city: city,
  duration: duration,
  employerName: employerName,
  phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
  summary: summary,
}
```

I'm looking for an ES6 way or some better practice for building an object containing the valuees of many selectors.

Comment: Show your HTML. Are these elements in a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about an array and a loop?

```js
const ids = [
  'name', 'city', 'duration', 'employerName', 'phoneNumber', 'summary',
];
const values = Object.fromEntries(ids.map(e => [
  e, document.getElementById(e).value
]));
console.log(values);
```

```html
<input id="name" value="a"/>
<input id="city" value="b"/>
<input id="duration" value="c"/>
<input id="employerName" value="d"/>
<input id="phoneNumber" value="e"/>
<input id="summary" value="f"/>
```